# Is it possible to scrape all the texts from the div classes within a div class at once?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

Im currently scraping using selenium and python. The thing is. I'm not being able to scrape all the text from all the div classes within a certain div class. Please refer to the below HTML for better understanding:

```
<div class= 'parent example'>
   <div class = 'child example'>
   <div class = 'child example'>
   <div class = 'child example'>
   <div class = 'child example'>
```

I would like to know if it is indeed possible to scrape all the given texts within the given four "child example" div classes at once by only mentioning the 'parent example' div class.

I appreciate very much your insights in advance

Comment: You should maybe look at the beautiful soup module, it;s a package for parsing HTML and XML documents. It creates a parse tree for parsed pages that can be used to extract data from HTML. That should allow you to be able to scrape the inner div classes

Comment: there is no text in that its class attribute ,

Comment: What you have posted is not valid HTML. We can't guess what the issue might be. If you want a good answer, you need to provide actual HTML. If you can't get the text from a child DIV, it's very likely that you aren't going to be able to get it from the parent DIV either but we'd have to guess without the actual HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There is no text in those element.

```
example=[x.text for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='parent example']//div[@class='child example']")]
print(example)
```

You can print child elements and collect them like so as they are multiple elements you have to use a loop or if that's all the elements you have in the element.

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='parent example']")
print(elem.text)
```

Would print all the text inside the parent class. or use by_class_name.